# User Configuration > Windows Settings >Scripts(Logon\Logoff)

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have added a script to Logon by going to the location "User Configuration > Windows Settings >Scripts(Logon\Logoff)".

I need to write a script which should remove the remove the script that is configured in Logon without the user having to open group policy editor, go to "User Configuration > Windows Settings >Scripts(Logon\Logoff)". 
Click logon and do remove by selecting a script.

or if i can disable/enable the logon scripts somehow??

any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

just put the file under `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` and use

```
del "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\file name.bat" >nul 2>&1
```

to remove it. `;)`

Comment: this works for a specific user only and not for all the users that login in that machine

Comment: @Kintaro you do realize that was almost ten years ago right?

Comment: Yes I do, and as I read it yesterday another one can read it today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the file
`C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\gpt.ini`

deleting the key `[{42B5FAAE-6536-11D2-AE5A-0000F87571E3} {40B66650-4972-11D1-A7CA-0000F87571E3}]`

and also delete the files

`C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\user\Scripts\psscript.ini`
`C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\user\Scripts\script.ini`